# regex to count number of single quotes in a string excluding 2 consecutive double quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to count number of times a single quote appears in a string but excluding those cases where single quote is directly followed by a single quote.

Example:

```
'singlequote','another single quote'
```

should give count 4 and

```
'singlequote','2 quote'' inside single quote'
```

should also give count 4

I did this

```
char quote= '\'';
int count2 = string.replaceAll("[^"+ quote +"]", "").length();
```

but this counts all the occurences.

Is there a way to do it in regex or do i need to loop through all the characters. Can someone please help with this

Comment: how do you handle triple or quadruple quotes?

Comment: Can there be escaped single quotes as well like `\'` ?

Comment: This has to be basically applied on DB2 query, there ' is used to escape a single quote, so if I need to update Kevin O' Brian in a column, i have to pass it as 'Kevin O'' Brian'. The quotes after letter O are the ones that needs to be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all `''|[^']` in your string. It will replace all *2 single quotes* and everything else but a single quote.

Example:

```
int count2 = string.replaceAll("''|[^']", "").length();
```

Which gives output `4`;

See DEMO: https://ideone.com/PqtRu6

Answer (score 2):

You can use this look-around based regex to match single quotes that are not preceded or followed by any single quote. Note that it will skip all the cases of multiple quotes so double or triple quotes will not be matched.

```
(?<!')'(?!')
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HvQe5j/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<!')` - Assert if previous character is not a single quote
- `'` - Match a single quote
- `(?!')` - Assert if next character is not a single quote

Comment: [A lookaround only based regex won't work here.](https://regex101.com/r/Pq0FG7/1) `(?<!')'(?!')` is a wrong approach with CSV.

Comment: Why not? It will match only quote that are not surrounded by another single quote on either side.

Comment: Because the  initial and trailing `'` will not be matched.

Comment: Yes that's right and I understand OP doesn't want to match them.

Comment: The count must be 4 in `'singlequote','another single quote'''` [while you get 3](https://regex101.com/r/Pq0FG7/1).

Comment: look at demo, clearly matches 4. But I am not sure look-behind available in javascript

Comment: **As per my understanding** count must be 4 in OP's example string not in your example since you have 3 consecutive quotes in the end.

Comment: @anubhava 
In my example, count must be 4. There are 4 `'` that are field qualifiers. Regex approach is not recommended here anyway.

Comment: I will let OP clarify this case since I read requirement that differently.

Comment: @anubhava this is pretty close to what i am looking for except the case which Wiktor mentioned i.e when 2 consecutive single quotes appear at the start or end. 'singlequote','another single quote''' or 'singlequote','''another single quote'

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do that, replace all 2-consecutive quotes with an empty string and count occurrences:

```
StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(yourString.replaceAll("''", ""), "'")
```

Make sure you import:

```
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
```

Comment: This does not solve my purpose as it will remove all the occurrences, i need to ignore only those which are coming in between a pair of single quotes. So 'David','','Kevin O'' Brian' should give me result as 6 and not 4

Comment: Hm, not sure I understood correctly then. I see 2 pairs of single quotes (8 single-quotes in total) in you example: 'David','','Kevin O'' Brian'